# How to get a Groupby count for my django template tag?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a total count of number of times a `category` has been used.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/components/categories_list.html',
                        takes_context=True)
def categories_list(context):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return {
        'request': context['request'],
        'categories': categories,
        'categories_count': categories.count()
    }
```

`'categories_count': categories.count()` does not work, as it just counts the total amount of objects in `categories`

Is there a simple way on doing this without working too much at the database level? I would like to get a count for the amount of times an object in `categories` has been used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (assuming `categories` is a field in your model?):

```
from django.db.models import Count
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/components/categories_list.html',
                        takes_context=True)
def categories_list(context):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    categories_count = Categories.objects.values('categories')
                           .order_by('categories')
                           .annotate(count=Count('categories'))
    return {
        'request': context['request'],
        'categories': categories,
        'categories_count': categories_count
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it at the template level? or given the snippet I posted above?

Comment: Yes, you should just be able to add this line and then change `categories.count()` to `categories_count`

Comment: I updated my answer to include your entire snippet

Comment: Thank you, so I managed to create this query set, tweaked yours a little because the `.objects.` inside `categories_count` was causing errors.

` categories_count = categories.values('name').order_by(       'name').annotate(count=Count('name'))` 

However this seems to be printing out the actual queryset and not the number itself. Also, it doesn't seem like it's the data im looking for. Im trying to find the total number of instances that a category has been used. A total count of all objects just returns the amount of categories available, which is not what I'm looking for